# Weird datetime format - Python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have received the data in .csv format which has a column date with weird format. The data was extracted from Oracle database. 
What will be the best way to convert?

```
Sample - 24FEB2009:00:00:00.000000  

df["date_format"] = df["date"].apply( lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d%m%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

Expected Result -

```
24FEB2009
```

Comment: So, you want to change the format of the datetime, thats not hard.  Given the information you have, you just need to trim your string.  For insight you can also look up what datetime variables there are so you can expand and change things later.

Comment: @Fallenreaper got it, thank you for responding.

Comment: Did you figure it out, or do you need any additional assistance?

Comment: Yes, as my data followed the similar trend, I stripped the first 2 digit and stored in day field, similarly next 3 in month and next 4 in year.